# Auto uninstall usb drivers on device removal

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb

I would like to auto uninstall any USB drivers the second the device is removed so there would remain no trace of the given device.

Comment: What's your objective? Because if it's stealth (no one knew you were there), then this isn't going to cut it - the system logs will still have traces.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to get it onto the system ahead of time, but the [Devcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx) tool can be used to remove drivers.